# How can I route my proxy service to another 3 local proxy services in OSB

Tags: osb, oracle-service-bus

Let me explain my situation. I recieve via a queue an XML file which will affect three different tables using ODATA RESTful services.

My logical conclusion to simplify the ODATA schema (instead of doing a batch) is to redirect the XML into three local proxys with different XQuery transformations. Then these proxys will call out the Web Services to update the database.

Can anyone help me? Can I use a for-each loop within a route node or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 options to route a payload/request to multiple different services (local proxies in your case) -

1. [Publish](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/doc.1111/e15867/proxy_actions.htm#i1315295) - Sends **asyncronous** request to end point. receives no response.
2. [Service Call Out](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/doc.1111/e15867/proxy_actions.htm#i1284898) - sends **syncronous** request to end point.
3. [Split Join](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/doc.1111/e15867/splitjoin.htm) - Sends **multiple simultanous syncronous** requests to multiple end points, then merges responses.

**I believe using 3 Publish actions is most suitable for your use-case.**

Comment: This is the correct answer. You don't need three proxy services as your case can be handled by one Proxy Service.